# how can I get the connection object from the cursor object for a database?

Tags: python, sql, cursor

I have a function that I run that will return a cursor for a database connection.

I do something like this:

```
cursor = sql.connect('database','username')
```

I am trying to get the connection object instead of the cursor. How am I able to do that? I am not able to access the function or modify its return behavior.

The connection object should be the parent object of the cursor.

Comment: Doesn't sql.connect return a connection?

Comment: It returns a cursor... I know. It is a custom module.